# access .Net field from F# when the field name is a reserved keyword

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I have a struct that has a field called `type`

How do i access it in F#?

c#

```
struct A {
   int type;
}
```

f#

```ml
let a = A()
let myThing = a.type  //error because type is a reserved keyword
```

How do i access the `type` field of `A`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a double backtick to qualify it ``` A.``type`` ```.

Answer (score 12):

You're accessing `type` like a static field. First, you need an instance of `A`:

```ml
let a = A()
let x = a.``type``
```

Comment: oops. forgot that in my question